# UINavigationController - back button causes data corruption

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, corruption

My application, which employs a UINavigation controller, ends by displaying numeric data to the user.

The problem is that the calculations will only be correct if the user advances directly to the calculation screen without hitting the back button. If the back button is hit at any point, even after the calculations have been performed, some of the values will be corrupted.

For instance, the first run, with correct values:

```
2011-06-17 23:52:16.644 BlahBlah [19690:207] A = 146.000000 and B = 6.000000
```

And the result if the back button has been hit at any point during the program:

```
2011-06-17 23:54:05.888 BlahBlah [19690:207] A = 146.000000 and B = 4.012038
```

The values will remain corrupted even on subsequent recalculations, and will only go away if the program is completely restarted (ie. I have to hit build and run again in Xcode).

I usually write in scripting languages, and so I assumed that this was a memory management issue, owing to my lack of experience with Obj C. I've pored over the code, however, ensuring that every alloc/new has a release, etc. I've run the debugger, which has nothing to tell me about this part of the code. I'm completely stuck at this point.

My question - what am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this issue?

Any assistance appreciated.

Further information - this is how I am passing variables around. myProfile is an instance of an object with attributes A and B, which are doubles.

```
CalculateView *CalculateView = [[CalculateView alloc] initWithNibName:@"Calculate"  bundle:nil]; 
CalculateView.myProfile = myProfile;     
[self.navigationController pushViewController:CalculateView animated:YES];
```

I should also mention that the values for A and B are loaded from a plist.

Comment: Can you provide more information such as how you are passing the calculated values around, where are they created and do you store them or reset them anywhere?

Comment: It is very difficult for us to identify problems in code we cannot see.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - further information added to question, as requested!

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this

```
CalculateView *CalculateView = [[CalculateView alloc] initWithNibName:@"Calculate"  bundle:nil]; 
CalculateView.myProfile = myProfile;     
//wrong code -- Where is Create1?
[self.navigationController pushViewController:Create1 animated:YES]; 
//right code
[self.navigationController pushViewController:CalculateView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rahul. You are right - there is a mismatch in variable names there. However, this was because I changed the variable name for the sake of clarity in posting the question - I just missed one (they were all called "Create1" in my actual code).